# why copy_to_user() is required?

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

As we all know that kernel has access to user space also. Thus, it doesn't need the special function - `copy_to_user()`. Why is it required then? The kernel can access the user space address directly. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because kernel does not want userspace to modify the passed data while it process the same data.

Copy from/to user

1. Validates buffer
2. Copy buffer to/from user so it does not have worry about data being updated in user space.

Answer (score 0):

Note that on some architectures, it's not implemented with a simple `memcpy()`:

- http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/alpha/include/asm/uaccess.h#L358

Comment: If you were to add some detail on what this function is doing as opposed to a simple memcpy() I would be happy to vote you up.